# Capture data from Python's subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to use a python2 module from python3. My idea was to have the python2 work in it's file, then use the subprocess module from python3 with args (to Popen) being `["python2", "script.py"]`. The methods provided return all strings. Is it possible to also capture data structures directly from the running process, for instance if I have generated a final dictionary in the script.py and I want to get that dictionary Object as the result of the computations in script.py. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: You could serialize your dict to a JSON in Python2 and load the JSON in Python3... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-serialize-a-Python-dictionary-into-a-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: You Mean writing the json to a file from Py2 then reading the file fromPy3?

Comment: Or just write the JSON on `stdout` in Python2 and read it in Python 3 as the output from `subprocess`.

Comment: I've added it as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize your dict to a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in Python2 and load the JSON in Python3. There is an example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-serialize-a-Python-dictionary-into-a-string-and-vice-versa).

Rather than pollute the filesystem with unnecessary writes and files, you could just print the JSON on `stdout` in your Python 2 script and then read it as the output from `subprocess()` in your Python 3 script. That will depend on your local environment.